# Script Not working Vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Good afternoon , I'm trying to make the following script type " 1" on the site of the field, but I can not ... I'm using the script:

```
WebBrowser1.Document.All("donatePage:donateForm:amount").SetAttribute("value", "1")

<input id="donatePage:donateForm:amount" name="donatePage:donateForm:amount" size="20" type="text" value="1.00">
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: This look, http://imgur.com/IOkgEDt

Comment: Try `WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("donatePage:donateForm:amount").SetAttribute("value", "1")`.

Comment: Look , I tried here , stop giving error, but it does not meet :( WHAT can be?

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Can you please rephrase it?

Comment: I tried the above script and yet he does not write on the website of the field, WHAT can be ?

Comment: Where is the `<input>` located? If it's located in containers I think you have to get them first.

Comment: It is like this, http://imgur.com/Ef5aIM1

Comment: I did not notice it was a div class :( sad that our,  Can someone pass me the script? http://imgur.com/JkVr6xr

Comment: Try getting the `<form>` first, then the `<input>`.